# dblclick SelectionInput card script services

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, card, scriptservice

Double clicking a selection input checkbox only triggers the "setOnChangeAction('functionName')" once but it will update the card UI checkbox appropriately; If the box is checked and then it is double clicked the box will visually appear checked but will only trigger the action function once so the back end doesn't match the cards state. Is there a trick to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should report that to [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for this? @kunuva

Comment: Hi, Welcome to S0! Here is some guidance on how to [best ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You could edit your question to make it easier for the community to help you.